# Constructor makes an object of the first parameter with all the results

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to register an user and I use a constructor class for it, but when I put the parameters in the constructor and make the query, it takes the first parameter that I passed to the constructor and puts all the information as if it were an object of that parameter. Like this:

[image]

And when I try to put a parameter to be able to use it like this this.username = username, I meet with this

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class User{
    constructor(user){
        this.username = user.username
        this.email = user.email
        this.birthday = user.birthday
        this.picture = user.picture
        this.password = user.password
    }
}
```

//////

```
async signUp(req,res){
        const newUser = new User(req.body)
        console.log(newUser)
        const result = await newUser.save()
        console.log(result)
        return res.redirect("/")
}
```

////

```
router.post("/signup", authcontroller.signUp)
```

Comment: Please use images instead of code. For more information, visit [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is as you've described then your problem must originate in the `req.body`. You are probably sending the data in a wrong format so try printing out the contents just to be certain.

If it is, simply adjust it to the proper structure.